Multiple if exists in PSQL function
I have code like that, I'm thinign if there is a better way to write it?
create or replace FUNCTION "catalog"."checkUsers"(userID integer)
    RETURNS bool
    AS $$
DECLARE 
  v1 bool = false;
 
BEGIN
    if exists (
          SELECT * from Table1
          where condition1 )
     then
    v1 = true;
    end if;

    if exists (
          SELECT * from Table2
          where condition2 )
     then
    v1 = true;
    end if;

    if exists (
          SELECT * from Table3
          where condition3 )
     then
    v1 = true;
    end if;

    if exists (
          SELECT * from Table4
          where condition4 )
     then
    v1 = true;
    end if;

    RETURN v1;
END

I want to refactor it because I'm not sure if the code is written in a clean way.

Add on exists and change the where with ORs, if you can handle true and null, use a SQL language function instead plpg

if exists (select something where condition1 or condition2 ... or conditionX) or if the condition is checking the same field: if exists (select something where field_val in (val1, va2, val3, val4))

EXISTS returns a boolean, there is no need to write this function in plpgsql, plain SQL can do the job.

It is impossible to provide a definitive answer with virtually no information given. (select something where contition literally tells nothing). However a generate template can be guessed at. Generally, a sequence of IF conditions combine in SQL into a set of OR conditions. You would get something like:
create or replace function checkUsers(userId integer)
    returns boolean
   language sql
as $$
    select exists( select null 
                     from someTable 
                    where stId = userId 
                      and (   condition1 is not null
                           or condition2 is not null
                           or condition3 is not null
                           or condition4 is not null
                          )
                 );
 $$;

The above of course makes assumption about conditions, the source of the conditions, and the use of the function's parameter. (See demo)

Thanks for the answer, you response if nice however I forgot to mention that each condition selects from different table

If you want an answer then provide the actual conditions necessary and how userId is employed. Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images.
